# Domino on mac client - weird doc behavior

Tags: macos, lotus-domino

I support an old (late 90s) Domino DB that has a growing number of Mac users. In some docs, layout regions become grayed out once you click anywhere in the doc even though it's still editable, i.e. if the cursor was in a text field and you type something blindly and save it, it will be there when you reopen the doc. It doesn't happen in all docs and I have found no pattern.

Any Domino designers seen any behavior like this? I don't this there is anything too weird in the code; onBlur or onChange used in some cases - that sort of thing. Nothing too complicated really. Thanks!

Comment: I think I remember seeing this behavior at some point, and it might not even have been on a Mac. Unfortunately, layout regions have been for all intents and purposes deprecated for, well... so long that I can't even remember how long it's been. My guess is that it's a bug in whatever version of Notes you're running on the Mac.

Comment: Indeed, can you somehow do without these layout regions?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will look at taking out the layout regions. There's hardly a line of underlying code I haven't touched since I inherited this DB, but I've left the layout more or less intact. I *think* this problem has only appeared in layout regions when it appears at all, though I'm not 100% sure of that.

Answer (score 1):

Layout regions are a nightmare to maintain: there can be objects with differing hide-when formulas stacked on top of each other that might be causing this.  I suggest making a copy you can work in without worry: inspect each object fully (keeping notes) then delete.  Keep drilling down until you hopefully hit an object that matches your grey-out.  If you don't find one, then it could be a bug as posted by Richard Schwartz.  As Richard and D.Bugger suggest, perhaps it's time to rebuild the functionality without using a layout region: layout regions never worked with a web browser.